Issue retrieving from field in Facebook Graph API for users, only working for page authors
I am trying to retrieve the from field for comments on a post using the Facebook Graph API. The from field is showing correctly for page authors but not for regular users who comment on the post.
I have ensured that I have the required permissions, including:
email
pages_show_list
pages_read_engagement
pages_read_user_content
pages_manage_posts
The API request I am making is as follows:
**GET /{page_post_id}/comments**

As per the Facebook Graph API documentation, this should return the from field for all comments. However, the from field is missing for users and is only available for page authors. i am also using  user access and page access token as docs suggest but still the issue persist.

Verified that I have all the required permissions.
Checked the API request to ensure it was correctly formatted according to the documentation.
Tried testing the request with different page posts and still encountered the same issue.
Use Facebook graph API Explorer to test different permissions and endpoints. but there is also from field missing.

I have been researching several Stack Overflow articles but i did not point any potential solution, and it seems that many people are experiencing the same issue in the Facebook community. It would be very helpful if someone could provide me with the latest information. I need to know whether this is an issue with V20 or if I am missing something.
I expected the from field to return the information for both users and page authors, but it's only appearing for page authors.
